# Pusher doesn't receive event when I use sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, pusher

I've an issue and I cannot understand what's the solution...

I have a Sidekiq worker

```
class UsersNotifier
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  require "pusher"

  attr_reader :event, :body, :users_ids, :image_reference

  def perform(event, body, image_reference, users_ids)
    @event = event
    @body = body
    @image_reference = image_reference
    @users_ids = users_ids
    notify_users
  end

  private

  def notify_users
    users_ids.each &method(:notify_user)
  end

  def notify_user(user_id)
    notification = create_notification user_id
    pusher_client["private-#{user_id}"].trigger event, body: body, image: image_reference
  end

  def create_notification(user_id)
    PrivateNotification.create recipient_id: user_id, event: event, body: body, image_reference: image_reference
  end

  def pusher_client
    Pusher::Client.new(
      { 
        app_id: Rails.application.secrets.pusher_app_id,
        key: Rails.application.secrets.pusher_key,
        secret: Rails.application.secrets.pusher_secret
      }
    ) 
  end
end
```

When I call in my controller

```
    UsersNotifier.perform_async(
      private_notification_params[:event],
      private_notification_params[:body],
      private_notification_params[:image_reference],
      recipients_ids
    )
```

My notifications are stored on db but I don't have any message in my pusher debug console.

If I try to call in console the worker:

```
UsersNotifier.new.perform(private_notification_params[:event],private_notification_params[:body],private_notification_params[:image_reference],recipients_ids)
```

Everything is fine, I can view events in pusher console...

Any idea?

**Solution**

I found the solution: I must reload sidekiq worker...

Comment: after reloading sidekiq, does it work?

Comment: yes, now it works...